# Liferay restart issue

Tags: java, configuration, jboss, liferay

I am a noob. I just downloaded the liferay with jboss 7.0.2. I had it installed on mt laptop by watching the youtube. I got it started by just using command line console. I successfully got it setup and running on the localhost. I turned off the command line console after I got it done.

Then I tried to open it one the browser by the `localhost` and it is not working now.  Now I cant go back to the platform.

I tried to go under the cmd again and enter

```
{the folder}\jboss-7.0.2\bin\standalone.bat
```

It shows me that it was calling another file called "standalone.conf.bat"

Now my environmental variables are

```
JAVA_HOME C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_04\bin
JAVA C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_04\bin
```

I need to start the thing start.. please help me

Comment: do you see any exception on console, what is the port for JBOSS ?

Comment: no. There was just no response.. I had been waiting forever and the console did not say anything to me. Now I had to start it all over again and I installed the tomcat. Again, if I have shut down the tomcat application how do I start it again?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you working with Tomcat (as per your last comment), then you should go to bin/startup.bat file (windows) or startup.sh (linux).

Now :

1) If your console does not start, that means, either some problem with tomcat configuration (CATALINA_HOME variable) or java configuration (JAVA_HOME)

2) If it starts, but hangs when configuration of data (default sql scripts), then there is a problem with database configuration that you did in portal.properties file, or default HS SQL DB.

3) If it hangs somewhere else, there must be some issue with the default port of the server.

Hope this helps.